# Django ORM: Filter with OR not returning object

Tags: python, django, django-models

The following code is not returning an object, but it 'should'. I'm passing the correct match for  mobile, email and incentive id, So what I'm I doing wrong?

```
return Recipient.objects.filter(
        models.Q(mobile=mobile,
                 email=email,
                 incentive__id__exact=incentive_id) |
        models.Q(friends_mobile=mobile,
                 friends_email=email,
                 incentive__id__exact=incentive_id)
    ).order_by(
        '-date_created')[:1].get()
```

Comment: I've never seen `get()` used in that fashion (i.e. without any arguments). I also don't thing this use is documented. I  could see that working, but if you are having problems, that's the first thing I would check.

Comment: If I just check one parameter e.g friends_mobile and mobile in both OR statement it works perfectly, but not with multiple arguments passed. I just want to make sure I only returned one object .get() seemed to do that for me.

Comment: Ok, you would normally use just `[0]` or [`.first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) instead of `[:1].get()`, but clearly that's not the source of the problem.

Comment: One more diagnostic question, don't feel offended if you find this to be obvious - you do realize that this require for both email and mobile to match? In other words if you were to translate this statement into a pseudo-code it would look something like this: `if (mobile == mobile_value and email == email_value and incentive == incentive_value) or (friends_mobile == mobile_value and friends_email == email_vale and incentive == incentive_value)` - the point being arguments passed to Q are linked using AND.

Comment: "is not returning an object" - what does it return instead?

Comment: I don't think this is the solution to your problem but since there is only one desired `incentive_id` you could filter others out before Q filtering: `Recipient.objects.filter(incentive__id__exact=incentive_id).filter(models.Q(mobile=mobile, email=email) | models.Q(friends_mobile=mobile, friends_email=email)).order_by('-date_created')[:1].get()`

Comment: So you're quite sure that there are objects that match all conditions?

Comment: @Ludwik Trammer  pseudo I'm trying to match: (mobile=mobile,
                 email=email,
                 incentive__id__exact=incentive_id) OR (friends_mobile=mobile,
                 friends_email=email,
                 incentive__id__exact=incentive_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `.get()` is problematic. It will return an object if using a QuerySet with only one object, but if there's more it will throw a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error and if the QuerySet is empty it will throw a `DoesNotExist` Error.

So the problem is very probably a QuerySet that does not apply to the specific condition you require. The solution? Return a default value.

Finally, you can use `[0]` instead of limiting to one object and then fetching it, and also, as @pythonishvili mentioned, you could pre-filter on the incentive. summing it all up, it should look like so (I split the query across multiple lines for better readability):

```
qs = Recipient.objects.filter(incentive__id__exact=incentive_id) #common filter
qs = qs.filter(models.Q(mobil‌​e=mobile, email=email) | 
               models.Q(friends_mobile=mobile, friends_email=email))
qs = qs.order_by('-date_created')
return qs[0] if qs else None #or any other default you'd like to use
```

Comment: MultipleObjectsReturned was the issue!!!! yeah! for some reason my custom error handler did not reflect this.

Comment: are you sure qs[0] is not a performance issues over using [:1] on the filter. does your version mean I could get 3 objects and not 1 from the db

Comment: Why would there be any performance issue here? The differences between `qs[0]` to `qs[:1]` to `qs[:3]` (if there any) are probably negligable.

Comment: If you're using Django >= 1.6 you can use the `.first()` method instead of `qs[0]`

Comment: just being pedantic :) but these negligible differences with hundreds of queries?

Comment: I just tested it with `timeit`, `qs[0]` takes 368 microseconds while `qs[:1]` takes 96.4 microseconds. in percentage this is a large difference, but I'm doubting you'd actually notice it, even with hundreds of queries. And frankly, I don't know of any better way, really (except for maybe working with the QuerySet object instead of pulling out the object itself)

Comment: Oh and also, `qs[:1].get()` takes 476 microseconds, so that's definitly the least efficient way to do it